# Library for visualizing computation graph

Tags: visualization, computational-algebra

Does anyone know a tool or library (preferable JavaScript) that can visualize an equation as a computational graph, such that for example the sigmoid function with inputs $\mathbf{w}$, $\mathbf{x}$ and $b$:

$$
\frac{1}{1 + e^{-\mathbf{w}*\mathbf{x}+b}}
$$

looks similar to this:
[image]

I think that internally libraries such as TensorFlow or Pytorch generate such graphs, but can I extract the separate nodes in these two libraries. If it works with TensorFlow, that would be great as I can directly include it in my JS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :

- [Parsing mathematical equation to generate computation graphs by OLIVIER WULVERYCK](https://blog.owulveryck.info/2017/12/18/parsing-mathematical-equation-to-generate-computation-graphs---first-step-from-software-1.0-to-2.0-in-go.html)

HTH